# How can I get all squares on this sphere so that its coordinates are integer numbers?

Tags: diophantine-equations

I have the sphere `(x-2)^2 + (y-4)^2 + (z-6)^2 = 15^2`. I want to select all  squares on this sphere so that its coordiantes are twelve different integer numbers like this `{-8, 15, 8}, {-3, 6, 20}, {12, 9, 16}, {7, 18, 4}`. I tried

```
ClearAll[a, b, r, c];
a = 2;
b = 4;
c = 6;
r = 15; ss = 
 Subsets[{x, y, z} /. 
   Solve[{(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 + (z - c)^2 == r^2}, {x, y, z}, 
    Integers], {4}];
```

How can I find four points on a sphere to make a square?

**UPDATE**

```
ClearAll[a, b, r, c];
a = 2;
b = 4;
c = 6;
r = 15;
ss = Subsets[{x, y, z} /. 
    Solve[{(x \[Minus] a)^2 + (y \[Minus] b)^2 + (z \[Minus] c)^2 == 
       r^2}, {x, y, z}, Integers], {2}];
k = Select[ss, EuclideanDistance[#[[1]], #[[2]]] == 2 r &]
```

> {{{-13, 4, 6}, {17, 4, 6}}, {{-12, -1, 4}, {16, 9, 8}}, {{-12, -1,
> 8}, {16, 9, 4}}, {{-12, 2, 1}, {16, 6, 11}}, {{-12, 2, 11}, {16, 6,
> 1}}, {{-12, 6, 1}, {16, 2, 11}}, {{-12, 6, 11}, {16, 2,
> 1}}, {{-12, 9, 4}, {16, -1, 8}}, {{-12, 9, 8}, {16, -1,
> 4}}, {{-10, -5, 6}, {14, 13, 6}}, {{-10, 4, -3}, {14, 4,
> 15}}, {{-10, 4, 15}, {14, 4, -3}}, {{-10, 13, 6}, {14, -5,
> 6}}, {{-9, -6, 4}, {13, 14, 8}}, {{-9, -6, 8}, {13, 14, 4}}, {{-9,
> 2, -4}, {13, 6, 16}}, {{-9, 2, 16}, {13, 6, -4}}, {{-9,
> 6, -4}, {13, 2, 16}}, {{-9, 6, 16}, {13, 2, -4}}, {{-9, 14,
> 4}, {13, -6, 8}}, {{-9, 14, 8}, {13, -6, 4}}, {{-8, -7, 4}, {12,
> 15, 8}}, {{-8, -7, 8}, {12, 15, 4}}, {{-8, -6, 1}, {12, 14,
> 11}}, {{-8, -6, 11}, {12, 14, 1}}, {{-8, -1, -4}, {12, 9,
> 16}}, {{-8, -1, 16}, {12, 9, -4}}, {{-8, 2, -5}, {12, 6,
> 17}}, {{-8, 2, 17}, {12, 6, -5}}, {{-8, 6, -5}, {12, 2, 17}}, {{-8,
> 6, 17}, {12, 2, -5}}, {{-8, 9, -4}, {12, -1, 16}}, {{-8, 9,
> 16}, {12, -1, -4}}, {{-8, 14, 1}, {12, -6, 11}}, {{-8, 14,
> 11}, {12, -6, 1}}, {{-8, 15, 4}, {12, -7, 8}}, {{-8, 15,
> 8}, {12, -7, 4}}, {{-7, -8, 6}, {11, 16, 6}}, {{-7, 4, -6}, {11, 4,
> 18}}, {{-7, 4, 18}, {11, 4, -6}}, {{-7, 16, 6}, {11, -8,
> 6}}, {{-3, -10, 4}, {7, 18, 8}}, {{-3, -10, 8}, {7, 18,
> 4}}, {{-3, -6, -4}, {7, 14, 16}}, {{-3, -6, 16}, {7,
> 14, -4}}, {{-3, 2, -8}, {7, 6, 20}}, {{-3, 2, 20}, {7,
> 6, -8}}, {{-3, 6, -8}, {7, 2, 20}}, {{-3, 6, 20}, {7,
> 2, -8}}, {{-3, 14, -4}, {7, -6, 16}}, {{-3, 14,
> 16}, {7, -6, -4}}, {{-3, 18, 4}, {7, -10, 8}}, {{-3, 18,
> 8}, {7, -10, 4}}, {{0, -10, 1}, {4, 18, 11}}, {{0, -10, 11}, {4,
> 18, 1}}, {{0, -7, -4}, {4, 15, 16}}, {{0, -7, 16}, {4,
> 15, -4}}, {{0, -6, -5}, {4, 14, 17}}, {{0, -6, 17}, {4,
> 14, -5}}, {{0, -1, -8}, {4, 9, 20}}, {{0, -1, 20}, {4,
> 9, -8}}, {{0, 9, -8}, {4, -1, 20}}, {{0, 9, 20}, {4, -1, -8}}, {{0,
> 14, -5}, {4, -6, 17}}, {{0, 14, 17}, {4, -6, -5}}, {{0,
> 15, -4}, {4, -7, 16}}, {{0, 15, 16}, {4, -7, -4}}, {{0, 18,
> 1}, {4, -10, 11}}, {{0, 18, 11}, {4, -10, 1}}, {{2, -11, 6}, {2,
> 19, 6}}, {{2, -8, -3}, {2, 16, 15}}, {{2, -8, 15}, {2,
> 16, -3}}, {{2, -5, -6}, {2, 13, 18}}, {{2, -5, 18}, {2,
> 13, -6}}, {{2, 4, -9}, {2, 4, 21}}}

I think, we can select two elements of `k` so that two this elements perpendicular to.

With Maple, I get the result
[image]

> {[[-12, -1, 4], [-9, 14, 8], [0, 9, 20], [-3, -6, 16]], [[-12, -1, 8]
> , [-9, 14, 4], [0, 9, -8], [-3, -6, -4]], [[-12, -1, 8], [-8, 14, 11]
> , [4, 9, 20], [0, -6, 17]], [[-12, 2, 1], [-9, 6, 16], [0, 18, 11], [-
> 3, 14, -4]], [[-12, 2, 1], [-8, -1, 16], [4, -10, 11], [0, -7, -4]], [
> [-12, 2, 11], [-9, 6, -4], [0, 18, 1], [-3, 14, 16]], [[-12, 2, 11], [
> -8, -1, -4], [4, -10, 1], [0, -7, 16]], [[-12, 6, 1], [-9, 2, 16], [0
> , -10, 11], [-3, -6, -4]], [[-12, 6, 1], [-8, 9, 16], [4, 18, 11], [0
> , 15, -4]], [[-12, 6, 11], [-9, 2, -4], [0, -10, 1], [-3, -6, 16]], [[
> -12, 6, 11], [-8, 9, -4], [4, 18, 1], [0, 15, 16]], [[-12, 9, 4], [-9
> , -6, 8], [0, -1, 20], [-3, 14, 16]], [[-12, 9, 8], [-9, -6, 4], [0, -
> 1, -8], [-3, 14, -4]], [[-12, 9, 8], [-8, -6, 11], [4, -1, 20], [0, 14
> , 17]], [[-9, 2, -4], [0, -10, 11], [13, 6, 16], [4, 18, 1]], [[-9, 2
> , 16], [0, -10, 1], [13, 6, -4], [4, 18, 11]], [[-9, 6, -4], [0, 18,
> 11], [13, 2, 16], [4, -10, 1]], [[-9, 6, 16], [0, 18, 1], [13, 2, -4]
> , [4, -10, 11]], [[-8, -7, 8], [-3, 2, 20], [12, -1, 16], [7, -10, 4]]
> , [[-8, -6, 11], [-3, 6, 20], [12, 2, 17], [7, -10, 8]], [[-8, -1, -4]
> , [-3, 18, 4], [12, 9, 16], [7, -10, 8]], [[-8, -1, -4], [0, 18, 1], [
> 12, 9, 16], [4, -10, 11]], [[-8, -1, 16], [-3, -10, 4], [12, -7, 8], [
> 7, 2, 20]], [[-8, -1, 16], [-3, 18, 8], [12, 9, -4], [7, -10, 4]], [[-
> 8, -1, 16], [0, 18, 11], [12, 9, -4], [4, -10, 1]], [[-8, 2, -5], [-3
> , 18, 8], [12, 6, 17], [7, -10, 4]], [[-8, 2, 17], [-3, -10, 8], [12,
> -6, 11], [7, 6, 20]], [[-8, 2, 17], [-3, 18, 4], [12, 6, -5], [7, -10
> , 8]], [[-8, 6, -5], [-3, -10, 8], [12, 2, 17], [7, 18, 4]], [[-8, 6,
> 17], [-3, -10, 4], [12, 2, -5], [7, 18, 8]], [[-8, 6, 17], [-3, 18, 8]
> , [12, 14, 11], [7, 2, 20]], [[-8, 9, -4], [-3, -10, 4], [12, -1, 16]
> , [7, 18, 8]], [[-8, 9, -4], [0, -10, 1], [12, -1, 16], [4, 18, 11]],
> [[-8, 9, 16], [-3, -10, 8], [12, -1, -4], [7, 18, 4]], [[-8, 9, 16], [
> -3, 18, 4], [12, 15, 8], [7, 6, 20]], [[-8, 9, 16], [0, -10, 11], [12
> , -1, -4], [4, 18, 1]], [[-8, 14, 11], [-3, 2, 20], [12, 6, 17], [7,
> 18, 8]], [[-8, 15, 8], [-3, 6, 20], [12, 9, 16], [7, 18, 4]], [[0, -1
> , 20], [4, 14, 17], [16, 9, 8], [12, -6, 11]], [[0, 9, 20], [4, -6, 17
> ], [16, -1, 8], [12, 14, 11]]}

Comment: `a = 1;
b = 2;
c = 5;` or `a = 2;
b = 4;
c = 6;`? Somewhat related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/181239/1871

Comment: I wonder if `PowersRepresentations` can be used here in a neat way (after shifting sphere to the origin)?

Edit: after reading the link from @xzczd, I definitely think you should explore `PowersRepresentations` as it just seems very natural to use here for finding integer valued coordinates on a spherical surface

Comment: @xzczd I am trying. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I retract my last comment (now deleted). If all the squares are needed, the method under [your previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/288699/1871) is not enough.

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question. From the code provided I had thought it was to find integer triples on the sphere surface. But reading again it seems the idea is to find quartets of those triples that give a square (hence of necessity are coplanar).

Comment: Maybe post the ruslts of the Maple in text form in order to compare with the result of Mathematica.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- For four points `{p1,p2,p3,p4}` on the sphere, if `exist` two segments bisect each other `(p1 + p2)/2 ==( p3 + p4)/2` and perpendicularly `(p1 - p2) . (p3 - p4) == 0`, then `{p1,p2,p3,p4}` build a square.

```
Clear[test0,test];
test0[{p1_, p2_, p3_, 
    p4_}] := (p1 + p2 == p3 + p4 && (p1 - p2) . (p3 - p4) == 0);
test[{p1_, p2_, p3_, p4_}] := 
 test0[{p1, p2, p3, p4}] || test0[{p1, p3, p2, p4}] || 
  test0[{p1, p4, p2, p3}]
```

```
ClearAll[a, b, r, c,ss];
a = 2;
b = 4;
c = 6;
r = 15;
ss = 
 Subsets[{x, y, z} /. 
   Solve[{(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 + (z - c)^2 == r^2}, {x, y, z}, 
    Integers], {4}];
squares = Pick[ss, test /@ ss];
squaresPoints = (Polygon /@ (ConvexHullRegion /@ squares)[[;; , 
      1]])[[;; , 1]]
```

```
Graphics3D[{Polygon /@ RandomSample[squaresPoints, 5], Opacity[.2], 
  Ball[{2, 4, 6}, 15]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

- The 327 squares are different.

```
Outer[Boole@RegionEqual[#1, #2] &, Polygon /@ squaresPoints, 
  Polygon /@ squaresPoints] == IdentityMatrix[Length@squaresPoints]
```

> `True`

- If we want the twelve different integer numbers,we can select it from the 327 squares. There are only 40 such squares.

```
list=Select[squaresPoints, Length@*Union @@ # == 12 &]
```

> ```
>  {{{-12, -1, 4}, {-9, 14, 8}, {0, 9, 20}, {-3, -6, 16}}, {{-12, -1, 
>    8}, {-9, 14, 4}, {0, 9, -8}, {-3, -6, -4}}, {{-12, -1, 8}, {-8, 14,
>     11}, {4, 9, 20}, {0, -6, 17}}, {{-3, 14, -4}, {-12, 2, 1}, {-9, 6,
>     16}, {0, 18, 11}}, {{-12, 2, 1}, {-8, -1, 16}, {4, -10, 
>    11}, {0, -7, -4}}, {{0, 18, 1}, {-3, 14, 16}, {-12, 2, 11}, {-9, 
>    6, -4}}, {{0, -7, 16}, {-12, 2, 11}, {-8, -1, -4}, {4, -10, 
>    1}}, {{-12, 6, 1}, {-9, 2, 16}, {0, -10, 11}, {-3, -6, -4}}, {{0, 
>    15, -4}, {-12, 6, 1}, {-8, 9, 16}, {4, 18, 11}}, {{-3, -6, 
>    16}, {-12, 6, 11}, {-9, 2, -4}, {0, -10, 1}}, {{0, 15, 16}, {-12, 
>    6, 11}, {-8, 9, -4}, {4, 18, 1}}, {{-3, 14, 16}, {-12, 9, 
>    4}, {-9, -6, 8}, {0, -1, 20}}, {{-12, 9, 8}, {-9, -6, 
>    4}, {0, -1, -8}, {-3, 14, -4}}, {{-12, 9, 8}, {-8, -6, 11}, {4, -1,
>     20}, {0, 14, 17}}, {{-9, 2, -4}, {0, -10, 11}, {13, 6, 16}, {4, 
>    18, 1}}, {{-9, 2, 16}, {0, -10, 1}, {13, 6, -4}, {4, 18, 
>    11}}, {{13, 2, 16}, {4, -10, 1}, {-9, 6, -4}, {0, 18, 11}}, {{-9, 
>    6, 16}, {0, 18, 1}, {13, 2, -4}, {4, -10, 11}}, {{7, -10, 
>    4}, {-8, -7, 8}, {-3, 2, 20}, {12, -1, 16}}, {{-8, -6, 11}, {-3, 6,
>     20}, {12, 2, 17}, {7, -10, 8}}, {{7, -10, 8}, {-8, -1, -4}, {-3, 
>    18, 4}, {12, 9, 16}}, {{-8, -1, -4}, {0, 18, 1}, {12, 9, 
>    16}, {4, -10, 11}}, {{-8, -1, 16}, {-3, -10, 4}, {12, -7, 8}, {7, 
>    2, 20}}, {{7, -10, 4}, {-8, -1, 16}, {-3, 18, 8}, {12, 
>    9, -4}}, {{4, -10, 1}, {-8, -1, 16}, {0, 18, 11}, {12, 
>    9, -4}}, {{-8, 2, -5}, {-3, 18, 8}, {12, 6, 17}, {7, -10, 
>    4}}, {{12, -6, 11}, {7, 6, 20}, {-8, 2, 17}, {-3, -10, 8}}, {{-8, 
>    2, 17}, {-3, 18, 4}, {12, 6, -5}, {7, -10, 8}}, {{-8, 
>    6, -5}, {-3, -10, 8}, {12, 2, 17}, {7, 18, 4}}, {{-8, 6, 
>    17}, {-3, -10, 4}, {12, 2, -5}, {7, 18, 8}}, {{-8, 6, 17}, {-3, 18,
>     8}, {12, 14, 11}, {7, 2, 20}}, {{-8, 9, -4}, {-3, -10, 
>    4}, {12, -1, 16}, {7, 18, 8}}, {{4, 18, 11}, {-8, 9, -4}, {0, -10, 
>    1}, {12, -1, 16}}, {{-8, 9, 16}, {-3, -10, 8}, {12, -1, -4}, {7, 
>    18, 4}}, {{-8, 9, 16}, {-3, 18, 4}, {12, 15, 8}, {7, 6, 20}}, {{4, 
>    18, 1}, {-8, 9, 16}, {0, -10, 11}, {12, -1, -4}}, {{12, 6, 17}, {7,
>     18, 8}, {-8, 14, 11}, {-3, 2, 20}}, {{7, 18, 4}, {-8, 15, 8}, {-3,
>     6, 20}, {12, 9, 16}}, {{16, 9, 8}, {12, -6, 11}, {0, -1, 20}, {4, 
>    14, 17}}, {{0, 9, 20}, {4, -6, 17}, {16, -1, 8}, {12, 14, 11}}}
> ```

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Thin], FaceForm[RandomColor[]], Polygon[#]} & /@ 
  list, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

- Check the result.

```
pts = {{-8, 15, 8}, {-3, 6, 20}, {12, 9, 16}, {7, 18, 4}};
MemberQ[Sort /@ list, Sort@pts]
```

> `True`.

Comment: Your results seems biger than Maple's results. I think, square `ABCD` and `DCBA` is one.

Comment: Please note the order of vertices of square `pts = {pa, pb, pc, 
   pd} = {{-13, 4, 6}, {2, -11, 6}, {2, 19, 6}, {17, 4, 6}}
pts // Polygon // Graphics3D`

Comment: I want to select all squares on this sphere so that its coordiantes are twelve different integer numbers.

Comment: @Laurenso  I have check the 327 squaresPoints,they are different.

Answer (score 3):

- Use the Graph Theory method from https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/289130/72111  make it faster.
- At first we search the space quadrilateral which four sides are equal by the graph theory method,then we select square from such space quadrilateral.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
{a, b, c} = {2, 4, 6};
r = 15;
pts = SolveValues[{(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 + (z - c)^2 == r^2}, {x, y, 
    z}, Integers];
pairs = Table[{i, 
     j} -> (pts[[i]] - pts[[j]]) . (pts[[i]] - pts[[j]]), {i, 
    Length@pts}, {j, Length@pts}];
groups = GatherBy[Flatten[pairs, 1], Last];
matrixs = SparseArray[# -> 1, Dimensions@pairs] & /@ Keys /@ groups;
adjgraphs = AdjacencyGraph /@ matrixs;
cycles = 
  FindIsomorphicSubgraph[#, CycleGraph[4], All] & /@ adjgraphs;
test0[{p1_, p2_, p3_, 
    p4_}] := (p1 + p2 == p3 + p4 && (p1 - p2) . (p3 - p4) == 0);
test[{p1_, p2_, p3_, p4_}] := 
  test0[{p1, p2, p3, p4}] || test0[{p1, p3, p2, p4}] || 
   test0[{p1, p4, p2, p3}];
squares = 
  Flatten[Table[
     Pick[pts[[#]] & /@ VertexList /@ cycles[[i]], 
      test@pts[[#]] & /@ VertexList /@ cycles[[i]]], {i, 
      Length@cycles}] /. {} -> Nothing, 1];
list = Select[squares, Length@*Union @@ # == 12 &];
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Thin], FaceForm[RandomColor[]], Polygon[#]} & /@ 
  list, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Definitely a task for `PowersRepresentations`.

First find triples of nonnegatives with squares summing to 15^2.

```
nnvals = PowersRepresentations[15^2, 3, 2]

(* Out[35]= {{0, 0, 15}, {0, 9, 12}, {2, 5, 14}, {2, 10, 11}, {5, 10, 10}} *)
```

Now allow plus/minus signs.

```
signs = Tuples[{-1, 1}, {3}];
alltriples = Union[Flatten[Outer[Times, signs, nnvals, 1], 1]]

(* Out[38]= {{-5, -10, -10}, {-5, -10, 10}, {-5, 10, -10}, {-5, 10, 
  10}, {-2, -10, -11}, {-2, -10, 11}, {-2, -5, -14}, {-2, -5, 
  14}, {-2, 5, -14}, {-2, 5, 14}, {-2, 10, -11}, {-2, 10, 
  11}, {0, -9, -12}, {0, -9, 12}, {0, 0, -15}, {0, 0, 15}, {0, 
  9, -12}, {0, 9, 12}, {2, -10, -11}, {2, -10, 
  11}, {2, -5, -14}, {2, -5, 14}, {2, 5, -14}, {2, 5, 14}, {2, 
  10, -11}, {2, 10, 11}, {5, -10, -10}, {5, -10, 10}, {5, 
  10, -10}, {5, 10, 10}} *)
```

Take all distinct permutations, and then add the offsets (2,4,6) in this example).

```
permuted = Union[Flatten[Map[Permutations, alltriples], 1]];
offsets = {2, 4, 6};
triples = Sort[Map[# + {2, 4, 6} &, permuted]]

Out[46]= {{-13, 4, 6}, {-12, -1, 4}, {-12, -1, 8}, {-12, 2, 1}, {-12, 
  2, 11}, {-12, 6, 1}, {-12, 6, 11}, {-12, 9, 4}, {-12, 9, 
  8}, {-10, -5, 6}, {-10, 4, -3}, {-10, 4, 15}, {-10, 13, 6}, {-9, -6,
   4}, {-9, -6, 8}, {-9, 2, -4}, {-9, 2, 16}, {-9, 6, -4}, {-9, 6, 
  16}, {-9, 14, 4}, {-9, 14, 8}, {-8, -7, 4}, {-8, -7, 8}, {-8, -6, 
  1}, {-8, -6, 11}, {-8, -1, -4}, {-8, -1, 16}, {-8, 2, -5}, {-8, 2, 
  17}, {-8, 6, -5}, {-8, 6, 17}, {-8, 9, -4}, {-8, 9, 16}, {-8, 14, 
  1}, {-8, 14, 11}, {-8, 15, 4}, {-8, 15, 8}, {-7, -8, 6}, {-7, 
  4, -6}, {-7, 4, 18}, {-7, 16, 6}, {-3, -10, 4}, {-3, -10, 
  8}, {-3, -6, -4}, {-3, -6, 16}, {-3, 2, -8}, {-3, 2, 20}, {-3, 
  6, -8}, {-3, 6, 20}, {-3, 14, -4}, {-3, 14, 16}, {-3, 18, 4}, {-3, 
  18, 8}, {0, -10, 1}, {0, -10, 11}, {0, -7, -4}, {0, -7, 
  16}, {0, -6, -5}, {0, -6, 17}, {0, -1, -8}, {0, -1, 20}, {0, 
  9, -8}, {0, 9, 20}, {0, 14, -5}, {0, 14, 17}, {0, 15, -4}, {0, 15, 
  16}, {0, 18, 1}, {0, 18, 11}, {2, -11, 6}, {2, -8, -3}, {2, -8, 
  15}, {2, -5, -6}, {2, -5, 18}, {2, 4, -9}, {2, 4, 21}, {2, 
  13, -6}, {2, 13, 18}, {2, 16, -3}, {2, 16, 15}, {2, 19, 6}, {4, -10,
   1}, {4, -10, 11}, {4, -7, -4}, {4, -7, 16}, {4, -6, -5}, {4, -6, 
  17}, {4, -1, -8}, {4, -1, 20}, {4, 9, -8}, {4, 9, 20}, {4, 
  14, -5}, {4, 14, 17}, {4, 15, -4}, {4, 15, 16}, {4, 18, 1}, {4, 18, 
  11}, {7, -10, 4}, {7, -10, 8}, {7, -6, -4}, {7, -6, 16}, {7, 
  2, -8}, {7, 2, 20}, {7, 6, -8}, {7, 6, 20}, {7, 14, -4}, {7, 14, 
  16}, {7, 18, 4}, {7, 18, 8}, {11, -8, 6}, {11, 4, -6}, {11, 4, 
  18}, {11, 16, 6}, {12, -7, 4}, {12, -7, 8}, {12, -6, 1}, {12, -6, 
  11}, {12, -1, -4}, {12, -1, 16}, {12, 2, -5}, {12, 2, 17}, {12, 
  6, -5}, {12, 6, 17}, {12, 9, -4}, {12, 9, 16}, {12, 14, 1}, {12, 14,
   11}, {12, 15, 4}, {12, 15, 8}, {13, -6, 4}, {13, -6, 8}, {13, 
  2, -4}, {13, 2, 16}, {13, 6, -4}, {13, 6, 16}, {13, 14, 4}, {13, 14,
   8}, {14, -5, 6}, {14, 4, -3}, {14, 4, 15}, {14, 13, 6}, {16, -1, 
  4}, {16, -1, 8}, {16, 2, 1}, {16, 2, 11}, {16, 6, 1}, {16, 6, 
  11}, {16, 9, 4}, {16, 9, 8}, {17, 4, 6}} *)
```

Comment: Only solve `a = 2;
b = 4;
c = 6;
r = 15;
 SolveValues[{(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 + (z - c)^2 == r^2}, {x, y, 
  z}, Integers]`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question… As mentioned in the question, OP wants to "find four points on a sphere to make a square. " (Update: oh, you've already noticed this in the comment under the question. )